# Merge multiple Angular scope watch statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have multiple different watch statements in a directive that watch `scope` and re-render a d3 directive on different events (window resize, form submit, etc...)

```
window.onresize = function() {
  scope.$apply();
};

// Call render function on window resize
scope.$watch(function() {
  return angular.element($window)[0].innerWidth;
}, function() {
  scope.render(scope.data);
});

// Watch for data changes and re-render
scope.$watch('data', function() {
  return scope.render(scope.data);
}, true);
```

Problem is, I'm ending up calling render multiple times for the same event.  Is there any way I can merge these three different `$watches` into a more concise structure?  I had guessed that watching `scope` would also watch the `data` attribute of `scope`, but apparently not!  Why is this?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Why do you end up calling multiple times for the same event. Are window resize and changes to 'data' correlated? If they are separate events and mutually exclusive then your code should work fine.

Comment: No they aren't correlated... but I think the `scope.$watch...` segment is also being called when changes to data occur.  I didn't think it was originally, but when `data` is updated it's running it twice.  Basically I'm just wondering if there is a way to consolidate this code.

Comment: scope.$watch('data') will get called when data changes. When else is it being called? Are you saying that you change data and scope.$watch('data') gets called twice?

Answer (score 3):

Might not be the best solution, but it may help.

underscorejs' `throttle` takes a function and a minimum time between executions of the function and returns a function that will only call the function specified at most once every `wait` milliseconds.

```
_.throttle(func, wait, [options])
```

[info](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)